# Problem with fourier package, the text disappears

Tags: errors, miktex, fourier

I have decided to change font and heard about the fourier package. I thought I just had to type \usepackage{fourier} for it to work but the text then completely disappeared. Here is the document preamble

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,titlepage]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage[vscale=0.82, vmarginratio=1:1, hscale=0.8,  
hmarginratio=1:1,   headsep=15pt, footskip=20pt]{geometry}
```

I'm sorry if the question is stupid, I just have no clue how latex works, are there now two font package?

**More info** When I compile I can see

```
Trying to make PK font futri8r at 552 DPI...
Running miktex-makemf.exe...
miktex-makemf: The futri8r source file could not be found. Running ttf2pk.exe..
miktex-makepk: PK font futri8r could not be created
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Do you get any error message?

Comment: oh, i forgot some more packages, I add it right away

Comment: You have a faulty installation: the fonts are not enabled in the map file.

Comment: What do I have to install? Miktex again?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm no MikTeX user, so I can't help more.

Comment: but how can you do without miktex? what do you use?

Comment: I've never used Windows in my life. ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've never used anything else than windows... what tag should I add?

Comment: Note that there is a popular TeX Live distribution for Windows :)

Comment: You just have to run from the command line (both as administrator and as user): `\updmap.exe`.

Comment: you can add it as an answer, it did work (without the \ ) , although this looks like a magic formula to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What MiKTeX often doesn't do is this: after installing a font and the packages required to use it, the `type 1 fonts database` has to be updated. The reason is essentially that LaTeX uses conventioal font names and a system of metric files to compose the document, then dvips or pdflatex have to know where the real fonts are to be found. This is stored in several fikes named `psfonts.map` and the like.

When you install a new font these files have to be updated, which MiKTeX doesn't always do, so you have to do it on your own with the command line:
`updmap.exe`, both as administrator and as user.